# changing the value of the inout box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a form which is being created by some class files, it only creates the classname. However the background image is being set but with the value is being typed, I want to hide the background image.
I am trying this piece of script but it does not work:

```
 <input type="text" value="" name="b_fname">
 
 background-image:
 url("/site/vitiscellars/images/basic_theme/your_name_bg.jpg");
```

This is my piece of test code:

#### javascript

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j(document).ready(function() {
 
 $j('.b_fname').click(function() {  
     alert('Handler for called'); });     
 });
```

Do know why this piece of code is not working.

Comment: it's full of syntax errors...

Comment: you are using `$('.b_fname')` means there must be a `class="b_fname"`

Comment: @SomekidwithHTML: The JavaScript is fine, no syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have name="b_fname" but no class. Add class="b_fname" or change your selector to:

```
$j('[name=b_fname]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class=b_fname in your html for the text box.

Otherwise in your jquery selector do

$j('input[name="bfname"]')

Answer (score 1):

`$j('.b_fname')` selects class, not name. To get the class, you have to add the class to the input, i.e `<input type="text" value="" class="b_fname" name="b_fname">`.

Subsequently, you could select the element by name using `$j('input[name="b_fname"]')`.